# Easiest way to serve a HTML page during a test run in Java?

Tags: java, http

I need to serve a dynamically generated HTML page that is built in during a test that is able to be viewed by another device on the same network. I have attempted to use Jetty but it doesn't appear as that is my solution. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: You have java code that creates html and now you want to know how to view it in a browser?

Comment: Is it a pure HTML page which is dynamically generated by Java? Or is it a dynamic page such as JSP?

Comment: @takendarkk Correct, I have java code that generates markup and creates a html page. I need to be able to view that newly created page from another device on the same network.

Comment: @shaochuancs Yes, pure HTML dynamically generated by java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to use Jetty to do this. I was having unknown dependency issues which was why Jetty wasn't originally working for me.

Here's my Java code to build the embedded webserver.

```
    Server server = new Server();

    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    //allow connection from all internal ip's
    connector.setPort(8000);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setResourceBase(resourceBase);

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts=new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[]{context});

    server.setHandler(contexts);

    context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

    server.start();
    LOG.info("WebServer started.");
```